# Can you make an AWS S3 object private if it was already public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I understand that an S3 object is private by default.  Suppose (for the sake of argument) that I have made an S3 object public.  Now I want it to be private again, because making it public was a mistake.  The AWS console doesn't appear to provide any means to do this.  Is the only way, to download the file, delete it from S3, and re-upload it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in a video after posting this question.

As of the current AWS S3 implementation (March 5th, 2018), you have to:

- Go into the file (object) properties in S3 (e.g. by clicking the file in the S3 bucket overview)
- Go to the `Permissions` tab
- Under `Public access` click `Everyone`
- Deselect `Read object`

I do not know why I missed it several times on my first attempts.

Comment: How can I make multiple files private at once, the solution provided works only for a single file?

Comment: I can still access the file even though it is deselected.